# MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []: Trigger.correcttest : line 64, column 1

Tags: apex, trigger

can anyone tell me what is wrong with code below?

code:

```
trigger correcttest on SBQQ__Quote__c(after update) {

     if(trigger.size ==1){
          
          Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();

          for(SBQQ__Quote__c qt : trigger.new){
               if(qt.testcorrect__c && !trigger.oldMap.get(qt.Id).testcorrect__c){
                    quoteIds.add(qt.Id);
               }
          }


         Map<Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> qls = new Map<Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>([ SELECT Id, SBQQ__Bundle__c, SBQQ__RequiredBy__c, SBQQ__ListPrice__c, SBQQ__Product__r.List_Price__c, Promotion__c, Promotion__r.id, Promotion__r.Promo_Value__c, Promotion__r.Price__c,
                                                                                SBQQ__NetPrice__c, SBQQ__CustomerTotal__c, SBQQ__Product__c, SBQQ__Product__r.Name, SBQQ__Product__r.Description,
                                                                                SBQQ__ListTotal__c, SBQQ__Quantity__c From SBQQ__QuoteLine__c Where SBQQ__Quote__r.Id IN:quoteIds  AND SBQQ__Product__r.Name != 'Sales Tax' ]);

          Map<Id,Id> parentqls = new Map<Id,Id>();
          Map<Id,Id> childqls = new Map<Id,Id>();

          for(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql : qls.values()){
               if(ql.SBQQ__Bundle__c){
                    parentqls.put(ql.SBQQ__Product__c,ql.Id);
               }else{
                    childqls.put(ql.SBQQ__Product__c,ql.Id);
               }
          }

          List<SBQQ__ProductOption__c> option = [Select Id,SBQQ__OptionalSKU__c,SBQQ__OptionalSKU__r.Shipping_Processing__c, SBQQ__Required__c, SBQQ__Bundled__c, SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__c From SBQQ__ProductOption__c Where SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__c IN: parentqls.keyset() AND (SBQQ__Required__c = true OR SBQQ__Selected__c = true)];

          Map<Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> qllstupdate = new Map<Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();
            List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> listupdate = new List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();
         
          for(SBQQ__ProductOption__c op : option){
               //if( !qllstupdate.containskey(childqls.get(op.SBQQ__OptionalSKU__c))  ){
                    SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c();
                    ql.ID = childqls.get(op.SBQQ__OptionalSKU__c);
                    
                    if (op.SBQQ__OptionalSKU__r.Shipping_Processing__c == False && op.SBQQ__Bundled__c == TRUE) {
                         ql.SBQQ__Bundled__c = true;
                    }
                    ql.SBQQ__RequiredBy__c = parentqls.get(op.SBQQ__ConfiguredSKU__c);
                    ql.SBQQ__ProductOption__c = op.Id;
                    
                    //qllstupdate.put(ql.ID,ql);
                    listupdate.add(ql);
               //}
          }
          

          //if(!qllstupdate.isempty()) update qllstupdate.values();
          if(!listupdate.isempty()) update listupdate;
     }
     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the line item doesn't have an optional SKU, you'll try to update with a null Id. This results in the error you're getting. Try the following change:

```
  for(SBQQ__ProductOption__c op : option){
       //if( !qllstupdate.containskey(childqls.get(op.SBQQ__OptionalSKU__c))  ){
            SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c();
            ql.ID = childqls.get(op.SBQQ__OptionalSKU__c);
            // There is no optional SKU, skip!
            if(ql.Id == null) {
                continue;
            }
```